# Transitioning the browser to fullscreen revert to normal when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a web based management software, and want to add the option to enlarge it to fullscreen for just having as much space as possible.
To do this I've tried some jquery plugin and the following code

```
 function toggleFullScreen() {
   if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
    !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
     if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
       document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
     } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
       document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
       document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
     }
   } else {
      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
         document.cancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
         document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
   }
 }
```

The problem is that when I click on any link and the page reloads, it revert to normal mode.
This doesn't happen when clicking F11 on the keyboard.
It's an api's limit or there's a way to perfectly emulate the F11 mode?

Comment: _"just having as much space as possible"_ I don't think this is reason enough to warrant a fullscreen feature. Do you _really_ have an interface where you absolutely need those 100 extra pixels?

Comment: Some user install many browser bars like epson aol ecc, often is much more than 100px, and sometime the screen resolution is sub 1366px.
I just want to add an option to make it more usable.

Comment: @MelanciaUK this is not a duplicate because I have no problem entering or exiting fullscreen, but keeping the browser in fullscreen when the page reloads

Comment: Fair enough. Retracting the vote.